# windows screen capture

Tags: windows, screen-capture

I want to Capture a image of a process on windows , I have the handle of the window for the process . If I do a BitBlt with SRCCOPY and no CAPTUREBLT, SO by default the image should only contain the process window according to explanation in MSDN.

> CAPTUREBLT
>   Includes any windows that are layered on top of your window in the resulting image. By default, the image only contains your window. Note that this generally cannot be used for printing device contexts.

But I see that the overlapped windows are also captured.

How to capture only one window without the overlapping windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to capture the contents of a single window, use [WM_PRINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd145216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[PrintWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd162869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).